RAG with LlamaIndex SubDocument, how to persist embeddings
Im doing a RAG model with some documents.
Testing Llamaindex SubDocSummaryPack, seems to be a good choice for documents chunking instead of simple chunking the original information.
After using SubDocSummaryPack function, I don't find any way to store embeddings in a local ChromaDB so I don't need to embed again while no changes are made in the documents.
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader

# Here I load a 77 pages PDF
documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("data").load_data()


import os
from llama_index.packs.subdoc_summary import SubDocSummaryPack
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI
from llama_index.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbedding

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "%API_KEY%"

# Here I make the documents chunking 
subdoc_summary_pack = SubDocSummaryPack(
    documents,
    parent_chunk_size=8192,  # default
    child_chunk_size=512,    # default
    llm=OpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo"),
    embed_model=OpenAIEmbedding(),
)

# At this point I want to save my embeddings in my local chromaDB
import chromadb
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.vector_stores.chroma import ChromaVectorStore
from llama_index.core import StorageContext

# initializing
db = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="./chroma")

# Creating collection
chroma_collection = db.get_or_create_collection("quickstart")

# Asigning a VectorStore for the context
vector_store = ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection)
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)


# HERE I NEED TO PERSIST !!!












I had this same problem and found pickle worked well - not ideal, but works.
Create the subdoc pack:
subdoc_summary_pack = SubDocSummaryPack(
    input_doc,
    parent_chunk_size=8192,  # default,
    child_chunk_size=512,  # default
    llm=OpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo"),
    embed_model=OpenAIEmbedding(),
    )

Then save using pickle:
file_path='./subdoc_summary_pack.pkl'
# Ensure the directory exists
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_path), exist_ok=True)

with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(subdoc_summary_pack, f)

...and re-load using pickle:
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        subdoc_summary_pack = pickle.load(f)


Try
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_vector_store(vector_store=ChromaVectorStore(chroma_collection=chroma_collection))
index.insert(document)

This will automatically persist.
